# Get height of react navigation bottom tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

In my React Native application I am overriding the [Bottom Tab Bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html). However, the height is not constant across all devices. It varies if the device is in portrait or landscape mode, it varies if the device has a notch or not - it is always different.

I was wondering what is the best and most optimized way to obtain the precise height of the tabs regardless of device or operating system, just as if the Tab Bar was never overriden.

Comment: why dont you just wrap the navigation with a `View`, track its ref and subsequently the height. When the screen orientation changes you can adjust based on the new height.

Comment: also why do you need to get the height? can't you just let the body flex the max height available?

Comment: You can try wrapping under a view an use the following method: `<View onLayout={(event) => {
  let height = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
}}>Your navigation bar here</View>`